# Dagger 2 BindsInstance is not supported for ChildComponent that is bound through ParentComponent?

Tags: dagger-2

We could either have

```
@Subcomponent(modules = [XModule::class, YModule::class])
interface ChildComponent

@Singleton
@Component
interface ParentComponent {
    fun childComponent(x: XModule, y: YModule): ChildComponent
}
```

or

```
@Subcomponent(modules = [XModule::class, YModule::class])
interface ChildComponent {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun xModule(x: XModule): Builder
        fun yModule(y: YModule): Builder
        fun build(): RequestComponent
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component
interface ParentComponent {
    fun childComponentBuilder: ChildComponentBuilder
}
```

However, we can have

```
@Subcomponent
interface ChildComponent {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun data(@BindsInstance data: Data): Builder
        fun build(): RequestComponent
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component
interface ParentComponent {
    fun childComponentBuilder: ChildComponentBuilder
}
```

But not

```
@Subcomponent
interface ChildComponent

@Singleton
@Component
interface ParentComponent {
    fun childComponent(@BindsInstance data: Data): ChildComponent
}
```

It complaints

```
error: Subcomponent factory methods may only accept modules, but com.elyeproj.daggertwomultibindings.subcomponentthroughcomponent.Data is not.
    com.elyeproj.daggertwomultibindings.subcomponentthroughcomponent.Data data, @org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                                                          ^
```

I thought this support is already done through https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/616?

Comment: You should use `@BindsInstance` only inside interfaces marked with `@Factory` or `@Builder` - that's why error happened

Comment: I know that `@BindsInstance` can only be used within Builder, but as proposed by Jake Wharton https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/616, this should ideally be supported on the abstract function parameter,